# what is the right way to get on line of data from db to an asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net

i need to get on line of data to a web site page (title,body...).
what is the right way to get the data?

dataset or datatable or ...?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think it's best to use [Linq to SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx) or [EF 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/aa937723) now.

Comment: if its just a small amount of simple data, those are prety heavy for the task, a simple DataReader would do.

Comment: for now i dont want to use linq or ef4.